# Negative learning implementation in pytorch

Tags: loss-function, pytorch

I have read a paper on Negative Learning: https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.07387.
The idea is that you can train a network not only by telling what label of the sample is, but by telling what it surely is not.
Let's call the latter a **"negative" label**.

An excerpt from the paper says (top formula is for usual "positive" label loss (**PL**), bottom - for "negative" label loss (**NL**):

[image: An excerpt from the paper]

I have a problem where "negative" labels collection is much easier than labeling each sample. So it is tempting to use it.

Is there some implementation of such a loss function in pytorch? Or should I write a custom loss layer code? If so, how should I do it?

Comment: It seems that you would have to create a custom loss function for this, which can be done relatively easily in pytorch by either creating a custom python function or using the `nn.Module` class (see also [this webpage](https://neptune.ai/blog/pytorch-loss-functions)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One implementation is

```py
( (loss+loss_neg) / (float((labels>=0).sum())+float((labels_neg[:,0]>=0).sum())) ).backward()
```

from [NLNL-Negative-Learning-for-Noisy-Labels GitHub repo](https://github.com/ydkim1293/NLNL-Negative-Learning-for-Noisy-Labels).